# Displaying images like a presentation without showing the desktop during update

Tags: python, c++, linux, qt, qt4

I'm trying to display images that are stored under ./pics directory in a row like a presentation on my secondary monitor using the following Python code under Xubuntu 14.04.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def displayImage( impath ):

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtGui.QMainWindow()

    # Select monitor
    screenres = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(1);
    window.move(QtCore.QPoint(screenres.x(), screenres.y()))
    window.resize(screenres.width(), screenres.height())

    # Set the image to be shown
    pic = QtGui.QLabel(window)
    pic.setGeometry(0, 0, 1960, 1080)
    pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap( impath ))

    window.showFullScreen()
    app.exec_()

    return

def controller( imdir ):

    # List the contents of the directory
    im_paths = os.listdir( imdir )

    # Keep only image files 
    pc = list(im_paths)
    for p in pc:
        print p
        if not p.split('.')[-1] in [ 'jpg', 'JPG', 'png', 'PNG' ]:
            im_paths.remove( p )

    if not im_paths:
        return 1

    # Start showing the images by calling project function as a new process (multiprocessing module)
    for f in im_paths:

        print 'Showing image:', p, '...'

        # Run project process
        p = mp.Process( target=displayImage, args=( imdir+f, ) )
        p.start()

        # Keep dispaying image for 3 seconds 
        time.sleep(2)

        p.terminate()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

    controller( './pics/' )
    exit(0)
```

**The issue**

There is a time interval when the process that displays the image A is terminated and until the process
that displays the image B to come up where the application displays nothing and for a moment the desktop is presented destroying the user experience.

Any ideas how to display images using Qt4 continuously?

PS. Answers that involve matplotlib and/or opencv may be accepted but I think that the straight forward path is through Qt.

Comment: Just a question: Why do you launch a new QApplication for every image you display and don't just launch one and not just update the image in the ``Pixmap``? Initialization properly takes time. And then  while you display one image already , create a new ``QPixmap`` and use ``QPixmap.swap`` to switch after ``x`` seconds?

Comment: Hi! I'm not experienced on Qt so I cannot imagine what is the optimal solution. Your answer seems to be a nice idea! So, I'm working on it. Could you provide an example on using the QPixmap.swap method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the solution. The alexblae's idea that the qt application should not be restarted on each image update was the key point. But first... I had to understand in some detail the architecture of the Qt framework, how the one class inherits from another and how events are generated and handled.

Let me quote the updated code in order other users to review and get advantage when facing similar problems.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
import os
import time

class Pic( QtGui.QLabel ):
    def __init__( self, w, im_paths ):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self,w)
        self.ims = im_paths
        # Set the first image that will be displayed
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap( self.ims[0] ) )
        self.i = 1

    # Catch timer events. On each event display the next image
    def timerEvent(self):     
        # Update the displayed image    
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap( self.ims[self.i] ) )
        self.i = ( self.i + 1 ) % len( self.ims )

def displayImages( im_paths ):

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QtGui.QMainWindow()

    screenres = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(1);
    window.move(QtCore.QPoint(screenres.x(), screenres.y()))
    window.resize(screenres.width(), screenres.height())

    pic = Pic(window, im_paths)
    pic.setGeometry(0, 0, 1960, 1080)

    window.showFullScreen()

    # Generate a timerEvent every 1 second. On each second the handler of
    # the event updates the displayed image
    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(pic.timerEvent)
    timer.start(1000)   #1 second

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def controller( imdir ):

    # List the contents of the directory
    im_paths = sorted( os.listdir( imdir ) )

    for i, path in enumerate( im_paths ):
        im_paths[i] = imdir + '/' + path

    # Keep only image files 
    pc = list(im_paths)
    for p in pc:
        if not p.split('.')[-1] in [ 'jpg', 'JPG', 'png', 'PNG' ]:
            im_paths.remove( p )

    if not im_paths:
        return 1

    # Run project process
    p = mp.Process( target=displayImages, args=( im_paths, ) )
    p.start()

    # Keep displaying images for 1 minute
    time.sleep(5)
    p.terminate()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

    controller( './pics/' )
    exit(0)
```

Pic class inherits from QLabel in order the timerEvent method to be defined. Using timer events we are able to inform the qt app when to update the displayed image.

Also, let me note that the usage of the multiprocessing module seems to be a bit overkill. Someone may call the displayImages function directly.

Comment: Is this specific to a Linux system?

Comment: No, the code can be executed on both Linux and Windows systems. The only dependency is the Qt framework.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this using OpenCV with python.

Here is the code along with the explanation:

```
import cv2    # for read/display images
import glob   # for linking to image file (.jpg)

#--- following is the directory containing my images of jpg format ---
jpg_files=glob.glob("C:/Users/Desktop/Stack/*.jpg")

#--- Here I run through every image file, read it and then display it with a lapse time of 1 second ---
for img_no in range(len(jpg_files)):  
    x = jpg_files[img_no]    
    img = cv2.imread(x,1)
    cv2.imshow('BINGO.jpg',img)
    cv2.waitKey(1000)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hope this helps 
:D

Comment: Hi Jeru! Thank you for your efforts! This solution doesn't fit well because of lack of specific requirements the solution should cover: a) full screen mode without window decorator and b) ability to choose specific monitor.

Comment: Hmmm glad I could provide some insight. Do check the functionality of `cv2.namedWindow()`.. it might help.

Comment: Do post a solution if you come across one :)

Comment: Just added the solution.